# Find and Replace Text using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I have a file that comes in daily with order information. The vendor sends font codes that I do not want included. I am trying to remove the font codes:

It comes in like this:

> PERSONALIZATION:
>   J#616
>   BTS#P47
>   Tim#P46
>   Tailored Night*#none
>   Macy#P46 Frank#P46

I would like the result to look like this:

> PERSONALIZATION:
>   J
>   BTS
>   Tim
>   Tailored Night
>   Macy Frank

This is the code:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("#616", "#P46", "#P47", "#none")
rplcList = Array("", "", "", "")

For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
          LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht
Next x
```

I get no errors but no changes are made to the text.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me.  Make sure the proper workbook is **Active**.

Comment: Or if the code in in the workbook you are using, you can use the following too: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend NOT to use ActiveWorkbook when you don't absolutely have to.

Since you know the name of the Workbook, declare it and use it.

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("name_of_your_workbook")
```

And then instead of ActiveWorkbook use the variable 'wb' e.g.

```
For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
```

Good luck